# How to update the pop-up note via API

Tags: api, acumatica

I'm trying to update the pop-up note via the API. I can easily update the top box (aka the Note) but I don't see how I go about updating the pop-up section. What's odd to me is that the Note doesn't even appear in the WSE, abut when I send the update it does work.

When I retrieve the record, it also doesn't appear to send the data that I have in the pop-up section, and I'm not even clear how I can add it to the WSE.

[image]

I've tried just adding it to the JSON update with a couple different names like this (tried popupnote, notepopup), and that still goes through, but only updates the top box:

```
  "note": {
    "value": "Travis Update Test!"
  },
  "notepopup": {
    "value": "Travis Pop update Test!"
  },
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Acumatica Support is below. In short you need to add a custom field in the items sectionm for the 2 notes and it works perfectly. When loading the items, if you plan to serialize into this class, add this `?$custom=Item.NoteText,Item.NotePopupText` to the end of your url:

```
{
    "id": "2a113b2c-d87f-e411-beca-00b56d0561c2",
    "custom": {
        "Item": {
            "NoteText": {
                "type": "CustomStringField",
                "value": "Regular note 2"
            },
            "NotePopupText": {
                "type": "CustomStringField",
                "value": "Popup note 2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```